# Shutting down the Kafka Listeners making the JVM to exit

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have created a Kafka listener using the Spring Kafka module. When I bring down all the Kafka listeners using JMX, the Springboot application is going down.  In this application, I don't have any other threads running other than Kafka consumers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because there are no longer any non-daemon threads running when you stop all the containers.

You need to start at least one `Thread` (not a daemon thread) to prevent the JVM from shutting down.

When you **do** want the app to stop, you must stop that thread first.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I also thought the same.

Comment: Another technique is to wait on a `CountDownLatch` in `main` - this will prevent the main thread from exiting (it's not a daemon). You can then count down the latch to shut the app down and `close()` the application context to stop all the listeners.